# Client/server pattern to hold local objects?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm working on an Android application that uses data from a server. I have a singleton Application object holding data that is used throughout the app (the User, its Addresses, etc.).

Until now, I was populating these data on the fly, ie. when I'm opening AddressesActivity, I call the addresses webService that populates data in Application before displaying the list.

However as the app grows and I need the same data in different places, I'm starting to duplicate code to populate the data. Plus I have to do checks all the time (if app.addresses == null callAddressesWebService, etc.).

I have some ideas to refactor this nicely, but I was wondering if there was a well-known pattern specifically for this particular issue?

**EDIT**

Here's what I started doing, any insight?

```
public abstract class LazyLoaded<T> {
    private T localValue = null;
    private boolean upToDate = false;

    public void get(final SingleResultCallback<T> successCallback, final ErrorCallback errorCallback) {
        if (getLocalValue() != null && isUpToDate()) {
            successCallback.onResponse(getLocalValue());
        }
        else {
            update(
                    new EmptyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse() {
                            get(successCallback, errorCallback);
                        }
                    },
                    errorCallback
            );
        }
    }

    protected abstract void update(EmptyCallback successCallback, ErrorCallback errorCallback);

    protected T getLocalValue() {
        return localValue;
    }

    protected void setLocalValue(T localValue) {
        this.localValue = localValue;
        this.upToDate = true;
    }

    protected boolean isUpToDate() {
        return upToDate;
    }

    public void setObsolete() {
        upToDate = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching pattern is the answer - look at [this](http://kircher-schwanninger.de/michael/publications/Caching.pdf)

Comment: Thank you i'll have a look :)